# MySQL Query Conditions

Tags: mysql

Can someone explain the following query? and what are the conditions that were set?

```
UPDATE
    `sales_flat_order`
SET
    status = REPLACE(status,'processing_pp_review','speditosda'),
    state = REPLACE(state, 'pending_payment','complete')
WHERE
    status LIKE '%processing_pp_review%'
AND
    state LIKE '%pending_payment%'
```

Comment: What is unclear to you?

Comment: I can't, at least not without seeing the table's structure and some sample data

Comment: So, when I said SET values I didn't mention AND, but when I wrote WHERE which is the intro of giving the previews command a condition and that condition is these two columns must have these specific values in order for the SET values to go through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finds rows where the status contains `processing_pp_review` and the state contains `pending_payment` (`like %...%` will check to see if the string contains this text in any position).

Then it will replace `processing_pp_review` with `speditosda` in the status, and `pending_payment` with `complete` in the state.